# Invoke-WebRequest on a Azure App url with token

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, token

I have an url from one of my azure app website. What I want to do is to do a Web request on this url by using token.

I managed to retrieve the token $token with the same method as [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/auth-v2-user). And the folowing command worked fine

`Invoke-WebRequest "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me" -Headers @{Authorization="Bearer $token"}`

Then I tried

`Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "myurl" -Headers  @{"authorization" = "Bearer $token"}`

But I got the folowing issue :

```
Invoke-WebRequest : {"code":401,"message":"IDX10511: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: '[PII is hidden]'. \u000akid: '[PII is hidden]'. \u000aExceptions caught:\u000a
'[PII is hidden]'.\u000atoken: '[PII is hidden]'."}
```

So it seems that the signature is not valid. Any Idea why and how to fix it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because the token is for Microsoft Graph API, not your API.

To acquire an access token for your API, add a scope to its app registration (Expose an API tab).
Then when acquiring a token, assign that scope's full value to the `scope` query parameter.
This full value will include either the App ID URI or the client ID of the API app registration + the value you define for the scope.

Comment: Also, when you call the Invoke-RestMethod , you have to pass the token as a secure string. To convert to a secure string, use the cmdlet ```ConvertTo-SecureString```

Comment: Thanks juunas, I just tried what you said by changing the scope value by the new scope that i just create "api://9f0 ...". When I invoke WebRequest i have now this error `Invoke-WebRequest : {"code":401,"message":"IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: '[PII is hidden]'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: '[PII is
hidden]' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: '[PII is hidden]'."`

Comment: Ok, that's progress. Can you decode the token at https://jwt.ms? The `"aud"` value there is the audience that the error is talking about. The API is configured to accept some audience/audiences, but this value is not one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I fixed this issue just by this small precision : for the scope I had to remove the prefix "api://".

Comment: That's odd :\ I guess in your case the audience in the generated token depends on if you use the client ID or the app ID URI in the request. Ideally the API should accept both.

Comment: removing "api://" worked for me!